# Select rows base on Subset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've a scenario where I need to write sql query base on result of other query.

Consider the table data:

```
id  attribute
1    a
1    b
2    a
3    a
3    b
3    c
```

I want to write query to select id base on attribute set.
I mean first I need to check attribute of id 1 using this query:

```
select attribute from table where id = 1
```

then base on this result I need to select subset of attribute. like in our case 1(a,b) is the subset of 3(a,b,c). My query should return 3 on that case.

And if I want to check base on 2(a) which is the subset of 1(a,b) and 3(a,b,c), it should return 1 and 3.

I hope, it's understandable. :)

Comment: Why not: `id=1 returns 1,3` and `id=2 returns 1,2,3`. You need to exclude ID that was used to get the set to compare with?

Comment: That's not an issue whether id=1 is returned or not. I can filter it but my main concern was to get ids which is the subset base on attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this query.
 Logic is simple: If there isn't any item in A and isn't in B --> A is subset of B.

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE 
(
   Id int, attribute varchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES (1,'a'), (1,'b'),
(2,'a'),
(3,'a'),(3,'b'),(3,'c')

DECLARE @FilterId int = 1

;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT sd.Id FROM @SampleData sd
)
SELECT * FROM temp t 
WHERE t.Id <> @FilterId
AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT sd2.attribute FROM @SampleData sd2 
            WHERE sd2.Id = @FilterId
            AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @SampleData sd WHERE sd.Id = t.Id AND sd.attribute = sd2.attribute)           
          )
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/QEOH35822)

Comment: What is the purpose of `;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT sd.Id FROM @SampleData sd
)` ? Isn't it pointless to use CTE here?

Comment: Use could use directly `@SampleData` instead of `temp`, and finally `Distinct` Id. It isn't different. But for example if `Id = 1` has 1000 attributes, then you call 1000 times NOT EXIST... for Id = 1.

Comment: OK, I get it. It moves DISTICT SORT form the final resultset after the first table scan.

Answer (score 1):

I would compose a query for that in three steps: first I'd get the attributes of the desired `id`, and this is the query you wrote

```
select attribute from table where id = 1
```

Then I would get the number of attributes for the required `id`

```
select count(distinct attribute) from table where id = 1
```

Finally I would use the above results as filters

```
select  id
from    table
where   id <> 1 and
        attribute in (
            select attribute from table where id = 1 /* Step 1 */
        )
group by id
having  count(distinct attribute) = (
            select count(distinct attribute) from table where id = 1 /* Step 2 */
        )
```

This will get you all the `id's` that have a number of `attributes` among those of the initially provided `id` equal to the number the initial `id` has.

Comment: I would prefer `count(distinct attribute)` to `count(*)`.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal You're right, thanks. I improved my answer